# Anchor property Cause the datagridview to cross mainform size

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview, ui-design

Here I have a datagridview in my categorycontrol i.e user control, when i change the anchor property of datagrid view to **top, right, bottom,left** this datagridview go beyond the form size, it does not fits in the form. It does not shows up as expected. Bellow are the sample pics First image shows the result when anchor property is set to **left and top** and the second image shows the result when anchor property is set to **top, right, bottom,left**. Below are the images.

Anchor property is set to **left and top**

[image: Anchor property is set to **left and top**]

Anchor property is set to **top, right, bottom,left**

[image: Anchor property is set to **top, right, bottom,left**]

Comment: Then your container's width and height are off the screen, too.

Comment: anchors never worked for me, always big troubles. Better is to use panels and the dock property.